# Table with rows of variable height

Tags: google-app-maker

I'd like to display a table of long text strings, say for an issue tracker.

```
user1 data1 comment1
user2 date2 comment2
...
userN dateN commentN
```

The commentX is in a textarea widget. I'd like each row to be high enough to show the entire comment without scrolling within each comment's textarea (there's no indication that the comment is bigger than the textarea so it's easy to overloook something). However, I cannot use the "fit to content" height for the tablerow, just "fill parent" and "fixed".

Is there a way to do what I want ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the fill parent and fixed is actually a limitation on the textarea itself, not on the table row settings. Is there a reason that it has to be a textarea inside the table vs just a label?

Comment: There is a reason: labels are not editable, and I wanted to make the comment field editable.

However, i could make edits not 'in place' and instead in e.g. a popup. Will try that, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Followup: Using a label works great!

Comment: I'll take it back. Labels are not great, as they don't preserve formatting (e.g. I can't show paragraphs etc - all the text gets reflown with complete disregard of spacing). Any help still hugely appreciated. Maybe there's an option for label to preserve formatting ?